# How to do urlsafe_base64 encoding in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

How to do urlsafe_base64 encoding in smarty?
I made a function like this:

```
function smarty_function_base($args, &$smarty){  
$data = base64_encode($args['str']);
$data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data);
return $data;  
}
```

it works, but I want to do something like this:

`base64(host:port:protocol:method:obfs:base64pass/?obfsparam=base64param&protoparam=base64param&remarks=base64remarks&group=base64group&udpport=0&uot=0)`

I use `|cat:` to make two string in to one string:

```
 {$link=$value[1]|trim|cat:":"|cat:$info['port']|cat:":"|cat:$info['protocol']|cat:":"|cat:$info['obfs']|cat:":"}
```

but it can't do things like this:

```
{$link=$link|:cat(base str="some_string_to_be_encode")}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I am a chinese student so my english is not too good :P

Comment: So i can only to write an api and use AJAX to do base64_encode??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these methods

```
function base64url_encode($data) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

function base64url_decode($data) {
    return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
}
```

Method 2

```
$encoded = urlencode( base64_encode( $str ) );
$decoded = base64_decode( urldecode( $encoded ) );
```

Valid base64 characters are below.

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=
```

**Edited:-**

You can assign the output to a smarty variable before like

```
$smarty->assign('yourVarforsmarty', you_custom_function_name($url));
```

and than in smarty template use simply

```
{$yourVarforsmarty}
```

OR

You can also create a modifier somewhere where $smarty class is created in your PHP:

```
$smarty->registerPlugin("modifier",'base64url_encode',  'base64url_decode');
```

and then call it in TPL:

```
{$string_to_encode|base64url_encode}
```

Comment: I know how to use php to do it, but the php file is encrypted.

Comment: i cant change that php file, only the tpl file is changeable.So i must do encode within smarty..

Comment: I had already made a function that can do url-safe base64.BUT the problem is that i want (base64_encode(base64_encode("balabala"))). It seems impossible in smarty,

Comment: and i cant do things like this   {$link=base str=$bala}